# Imported accounts in metamask are not visible using web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, ropsten

I have a node in ropsten network and created 3 accounts say a,b,c  using geth. Connected metamask with ropsten network and created other account 'd' using metamask and imported accounts a,b and c by passing JSON file. But account 'd' was not shown with eth.accounts in geth console.

When I connected metmask with nodejs by :

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)

  var ETH_CLIENT = window.web3
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
  if (error) {
  console.log(error);
  }


console.log('account0 ='+accounts[0]);

console.log('account1 = '+accounts[1]); 
});
})
```

accounts[0] shows account address of 'd'.
accounts[1] is 'undefined'.

How to get imported accounts from metamask in nodejs?

**And why account 'd' is not visible with command 'eth.accounts' in geth console? I have a running ropsten node at port 8545. But accounts 'a' ,'b' and'c' was not visible in metamask when I connected it. I had to import accounts..**

Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The accounts array is going to be always of length 1 and contain the account selected in metamask

Comment: And why account 'd' is not visible with command 'eth.accounts' in geth console? I have a running ropsten node at port 8545. But accounts 'a' ,'b' and'c' was not visible in metamask when I connected it. I had to import accounts..

Comment: Honestly I don't know